# How to get rid of CRLF will be replaced by LF warning in Swagger?

Tags: git, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm using  ASP.NET ZERO framework in windows machine, in that I have a refresh.bat file. It's used to generate proxy file by using Swagger. So once I run this file.it gives git diff as CRLF will be replaced by LF in proxy file even if there is no change. I'm able to disable the warning by using git config core.autocrlf false. But it still shows diff but with no warning.

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu cannot you help here?

Comment: Thanks for great customer support, it has really helped me a lot. Your way of handling customer is awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add a **.gitattributes** file to your project and the following line to always allow the **service-proxies.ts** file to be LF

```
service-proxies.ts text eol=lf
```